# Here I have tried to replace NaN value to replace with mode of column gender

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have tried to replace `NaN` values to  mode of column `gender`. Its not replacing. However when i tried to print mode result on `gender` column its giving result.

same thing I have tried for `age`, it got replaced.

```
a = mp.int(data['Age'].mean())
b= data['Gender'].mode()
print(b)
data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].replace(mp.NaN, b).head(16)
data['Age'] = data['Age'].replace(mp.NaN, a).head(16)
data.head(16)
```

Comment: `data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].fillna(b)`. `NaN` cannot compare equal to itself, so you need a different method that can catch it. What is `mp`, by the way?

Comment: object of numpy

Comment: The convention is `np`, not `mp`. It may be just a convention, but it's one worth sticking to because it's pretty much universally understood. `mp` makes me think of `matplotlib`

Comment: rogan Still its not working

Comment: Are you sure you have `np.nan` and not strings?

Comment: Code is gonna be illegible in comments. Please [edit] it into your question

Comment: Are you sure you have np.nan and not strings? what do you mean by this. could you please elaborate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found other alternative. Still, I wanted to know why the above code is not working. Can some body help me out.

Here is my alternate solution:

```py
data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].fillna(data['Gender'].value_counts().idxmax())
```